# Rplacing NaN with a year

Tags: python, pandas, function, missing-data, fillna

**Hello everyone**,

So I'm trying to fill in 7 missing entries by the date "2012-01-01".
I tried to create a function but got a little tangled up with the writing.

**gaming['name']**: represent names of games.

**gaming['year_of_release']**: represent the year the game was released.

I've tried:

```
def harry_potter_nons(row):
    for i in row[['name', 'year_of_release']]:
        if row['name']=="LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7" and row['year_of_release']==None:
            row['year_of_release'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('20120101')
        else:
            continue

gaming['year_of_release']=gaming.apply(harry_potter_nons,axis=1)
```

eventually, I got an AttributError:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_57/2529247191.py in <module>
      6             continue
      7 
----> 8 gaming['year_of_release']=gaming.apply(harry_potter_nons,axis=1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

/tmp/ipykernel_57/2529247191.py in harry_potter_nons(row)
      2     for i in row[['name', 'year_of_release']]:
      3         if row['name']=="LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7" and row['year_of_release']==None:
----> 4             row['year_of_release'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('20120101'))
      5         else:
      6             continue

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Can I please get a little help here?
Thanks

Comment: `fillna()` is an attribute for a dataframe. If you want to replace all the `NaN` values in a dataframe, you can use `Dataframe.fillna()`

Comment: Replace the error line by `row['year_of_release'] = pd.Timestamp('20120101')`. You already have a single `row` and select a single column in it so you have one value (None) which you can replace.